# Generate sets of subsets plus unused elements

Tags: python, subset, python-itertools

I want a python program that takes a list of integers and returns a list of lists of tuples that contain the subsets as well as the subsets with the rest of the values not used in the first subset, essentially getting all possibilities to combine the values in the list.

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

should return

```
[[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)], [(1,), (2,3,), (4,)], [(1,), (2,) (3,4,)], [(1,), (2,4,), (3,)],[(1,), (2,3,4,)], [(1,2,), (3,), (4,)], [(1,2,), (3,4)]...and so on]
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is surprisingly easy with library `more_itertools`. You can use the
`for` loop below to write your `tuple` level output and discard undesired
results.

```
import more_itertools

s1 = set([1,2,3,4])
subsubsets = more_itertools.set_partitions(s1)
print(*subsubsets)
subsubsets = more_itertools.set_partitions(s1)
for l in subsubsets:
    if l1 != sum(len(k) for k in l):
        print(f"{l} non-compliant")
        break
```

Output (added extra linebreaks)

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[2], [1, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4]]
[[2, 3], [1, 4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[3], [1, 2, 4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1], [3], [2, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[2], [1, 3], [4]]
[[2], [3], [1, 4]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```